# Auto-mapping network drive when a user logs in

Tags: windows, mappeddrive, home-drive

I used to know how to do this a few years ago, but I can't remember how I did it. I have one machine that is used by 5 different people. I need to map their home drive/folder when a user logs in with their credentials.

The client OS is Windows XP. The home folders are on a Windows 2003 R2 file server. There are no domains, and only a single workgroup in the network.

I would greatly appreciate it, if anybody could point me to a blog, article, or knowledge base that explains how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Windows XP?  Only WinXP Pro can log into a domain (without unofficial patches), for example.

Comment: The machine is running Windows XP Professional.

Comment: Did you found command for any username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have typically done this with one of the following two methods:

1. For machines logging into a domain (WinXP Pro only, not WinXP Home), create a batch login script that executes "`net use`" commands, or
2. Create a bat script that uses "`net use`" commands and put it or a shortcut to it into the startup folder:

`C:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

or

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: I use exactly this method. Startup folder rocks :)

Comment: This one worked the best. I still needed to adjust the security on all the home drives though.

Comment: What command you use net use? How to map to username whitchever it is? I get error 67

Answer (score 4):

**User Profile Home folder mapping (active directory):**

1. Right-click the account you wish to modify and select 'Properties'
2. Click the 'Profile' tab and choose 'Connect:' under the 'Home folder' section

**User Profile Home folder mapping (local system):**

1. Right-click 'My Computer' Select 'Manage'
2. Expand 'Local Users and Groups' and open the 'Users' folder
3. Right-click the user you wish to modify
4. Click the 'Profile' tab and choose 'Connect:' under the 'Home folder' section

**General drive mapping:**

See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308582) from Microsoft, and look at the `net use` section.

Specifically,

```
net use x: \\computer name\share name
```

To get it to re-map on boot, use `/PERSISTENT:YES` after the command:

```
net use x: \\computer name\share name /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with drive mapping. I already created a control that lets me map drives programatically. I also don't have active directory, only a workgroup.

I'll try from the profile tab for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in their user properties under the "Profile" tab.